# Битовый сдвиг для набора байт

Tags: c#, .net

Есть `byte[]`

Требуется выполнить для него битовый сдвиг влево или вправо с минимальными затратами.

В поиске решений я наткнулся на `BitArray`. Один из его конструкторов принимает массив байт. Класс позволяет выполнять различные битовые операции (AND NOT OR XOR), но не позволяет делать сдвиги.

Comment: А вариант со сдвигом каждого байта по отдельности в цикле вы не считаете за вариант с минимальными затратами?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440938/c-sharp-left-shift-an-entire-byte-array

Comment: @Regent, это, вероятно, неверно, т. к. надо переносить биты в соседний байт, не?

Comment: little indian или big indian? BigInteger не подходит?

Comment: @Qwertiy а это смотря что нужно автору. Лично я понял так, что значение каждого байта просто нужно сдвинуть, независимо от других байтов. И вот в качестве оптимизации сделать это как-то для целого массива. В стиле копирования массива вручную и с помощью `System.arraycopy` в Java.

Comment: @Regent, тогда бы он BitArray не предлагал?

Comment: @Qwertiy так ведь `BitArray` не позволяет решить ни вариант с независимыми сдвигами, ни вариант с зависимыми. Так что его упоминание, по сути, ни на что не влияет. В любом случае, зачем гадать - надеюсь, автор вопроса появится и прояснит ситуацию.

Comment: @Regent, его упоминание как бы предполагает, что он хочет двигать массив битов целиком, а не терять по одному биту из каждого байта, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Regent прав. Я приплел BitArray в качестве маркера моих хотелок :)

Comment: @iRumba так нужно сдвигать каждый байт по отдельности?

Comment: @iRumba, я теперь тоже не понял, что надо сделать))

Comment: @Alex78191, нужно сделать сдвиг точно такой же как для int, например. То есть на входе 11000011 11001111, на выходе сдвига на 1 влево хочу получить 10000111 10011110. Только это все для массива байтов, количество элементов которого ограничено только int.MaxValue

Comment: @iRumba скорее хотите получить хочу получить `10000111 10011111`

Comment: @Alex78191, нет, это уже циклический сдвиг. Да, он тоже нужен, но он выполняется через 2 противоположных сдвига, так что базовая операция - обычный сдвиг

Comment: @iRumba по-моему, вы всех запутали своим комментарием про мой вариант. Я вот как раз говорил про вариант, при котором в каждом байте происходит сдвиг **независимо** от результатов сдвига других байтов. То есть ровно про то, что привел Alex78191 во втором своём ответе. А вам всё же, получается, нужно делать зависимый от других байтов сдвиг.

Comment: @Regent, ну значит и я вас не понял. Короче нужно именно полное смещение. То есть весь набор байтов представляет собой единое целое.

Comment: нулевой бит нулевого элемента массива является нулевым битом всего массива, а 8-й бит старшего элемента является старшим битом массива, так? Это я для понимания расположения битов, а то ведь по-разному бывает.

Comment: @rdom, ага, все верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате у меня получились 2 функции:

Сдвиг влево

```
public static byte[] ShiftLeft(byte[] src, int val)
{
    var res = new byte[src.Length];
    var byteShift = val >> 3;
    if (byteShift >= src.Length)
        return res;
    val ^= byteShift << 3;

    for (var i = 1; i < src.Length - byteShift; i++)
        res[i + byteShift] = (byte)((src[i] << val) | src[i - 1] >> 8 - val);

    res[byteShift] = (byte)(src[0] << val);
    return res;
}
```

И сдвиг вправо

```
public static byte[] ShiftRight(byte[] src, int val)
{
    var res = new byte[src.Length];
    var byteShift = val >> 3;
    if (byteShift >= src.Length)
        return res;
    val ^= byteShift << 3;

    for (var i = byteShift; i < src.Length - 1; i++)
        res[i - byteShift] = (byte)((src[i] >> val) | src[i + 1] << 8 - val);

    res[src.Length - byteShift - 1] = (byte)(src[src.Length - 1] >> val);
    return res;
}
```

Функции "как есть" предполагают правильное использование. Для меня очень важна скорость, поэтому я не стал делать проверку на отрицательные значения. В идеале отрицательный сдвиг влево - это сдвиг вправо на то же число по модулю.

Так же можно было добавить проверки на нулевой сдвиг, на сдвиг кратный 8 и тд. Возможно, это ускорит общий процесс, но, как показала практика, такие случаи бывают реже, чем в каждом восьмом сдвиге, а каждое условие и операция добавляют дополнительное время выполнения.

И да, Regent говорил что-то про порядок байтов. Я не стал в этом разбираться, потому что тот вариант, который есть сейчас меня полностью устраивает. Если вы получите набор байт из числа типа `long` и выполните сдвиг моей функцией, то вы получите тот же результат, как если вы сначала выполните такой же сдвиг для числа, а затем получите из результата набор байтов. Набор байтов из числа я получаю функцией `BitConverter.GetBytes(theLong)`

На данный момент на моем компе мои функции выполняют 10млн сдвигов за 700-900 мс при величине сдвига 0-7 и время обратно пропорционально величине сдвига деленной на 8. То есть то же самое количество сдвигов на 8-15 выполнится быстрее, чем на 0-7, а на 16-23 еще быстрее и тд...

**UPD**

Указанное время на выполнение указано для Debug. В релизе все работает в 3-4 раза быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

```
#region сдвиг на 1 бит

byte[] myBytes;
BitArray gamma_value = new BitArray(myBytes);

int len = gamma_value.Length; //длина массива бит
c = gamma_value[0]; //младший бит

//создание массива типа bool 
//такой же длины как gamma_value типа BitArray
bool[] gamma_new = new bool[len]; 

//копируем массив типа BitArray в массив типа bool
gamma_value.CopyTo(gamma_new, 0); 

//копируем массив bool со сдвигом на 1ну позицию в другой массив bool
Array.Copy(gamma_new, 1, gamma_new, 0, len - 1);

//преобразование массива типа bool в массив типа BitArray
gamma_value = new BitArray(gamma_new);

gamma_value.CopyTo(myBytes, 0); //переводим массив бит в массив байт

#endregion
```

Comment: Очень неэффективно же, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy по крайней мере с минимальными затратами написания кода.

Comment: Мне нужны минимальные затраты на время выполнения (на ресурс компа)

Comment: @iRumba, попробуй SIMD?

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно конкретики?

Comment: @iRumba, ни разу не пользовался. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/04/22/c-vectorization-microsoft-bcl-simd/

Comment: Тут есть еще такою нюанс. На входе у меня массив байтов а не битов

Comment: @iRumba создайте BitArray.

Comment: Так мне вернуть тоже надо массив байт. Еще раз создавать BitArray и выводить из него байты? Надо будет погонять по производительности. Но для этого нужен еще один ответ как минимум. Может и сам чего придумаю еще

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле, в этом нет необходимости. JIT автоматически проведёт такую оптимизацию, если она возможна, т.е. в конечном ассемблерном листинге будут уже SSE-инструкции.

Comment: BitArray не конвертируется в byte[]. Короче все это очень затратно. Кстати, провел замеры сдвигов для byte, int и long. Они выполняются одинаковое время. Возможно, на 32 битной системе long будет работать в 2 раза дольше чем int. Отсюда делаю вывод, что надо оперировать элементами по 4 байта для 32 битных систем и по 8 байт для 64х. Надо только придумать как. Присоединяйтесь. Про ваш текущий способ скорее всего лучше забыть. Он очень затратен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, прочтите комментарий над этим. Может, это натолкнет на мысли.

Answer (score 2):

Идея состоит в ручном копировании битов. То есть если делаем сдвиг влево на 4 бита, то копируем в 0-й бит 4-й бит, в 1-й - 5-й и т.д. Соответственно, в, например, 15-й бит (2-й байт) копируется 19-й бит (3-й байт).

Для сдвига вправо - аналогично.

```
private static readonly byte[] bits = new byte[] { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 8, 4, 2, 1 };

public static byte[] ShiftLeft(byte[] array, int shift)
{
    var result = new byte[array.Length];
    var totalLength = array.Length * 8;
    for (var toIndex = 0; toIndex < totalLength - shift; toIndex++)
    {
        var fromIndex = toIndex + shift;
        SetBit(fromIndex, toIndex, array, result);
    }
    return result;
}

public static byte[] ShiftRight(byte[] array, int shift)
{
    var result = new byte[array.Length];
    var totalLength = array.Length * 8;
    for (var toIndex = totalLength - 1; toIndex >= shift; toIndex--)
    {
        var fromIndex = toIndex - shift;
        SetBit(fromIndex, toIndex, array, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void SetBit(int fromIndex, int toIndex, byte[] fromArray, byte[] toArray)
{
    var fromByte = fromArray[fromIndex / 8];
    var fromBit = bits[fromIndex % 8];
    if ((fromByte & fromBit) != 0)
    {
        toArray[toIndex / 8] |= bits[toIndex % 8];
    }
}
```

Comment: надо на любое число

Comment: @iRumba сделал для любого числа. Вечером, после работы, подумаю ещё над упрощением кода.

Comment: Это портит оригинальный набор.

Comment: @iRumba так вы ровном счетом нигде не писали о том, что вам нужна копия массива. Про сдвиг на любое число битов можно было догадаться, но про копию - это уже перебор. Опять придётся код менять.

Comment: Я не думал, что это нужно говорить. Подразумевалось, что функция должна работать так же, как для обычных чисел (типа int или long). Дело в том, что различные побитовые операции редко используются в единичном экземпляре. Как правило это набор операций, на подобие `A << 1 | A >> x - 1 ` (ROL 1). Ваша реализация подпортит жизнь программисту, который будет этим пользоваться.

Comment: @iRumba фокус в том, что операции над массивами не всегда возвращают новый массив. Яркий пример тому - стандартный метод `Array.sort`. Использование того же самого массива позволяет сэкономить память (под копию массива), а также время (если нужно копировать данные из оригинала в копию). Конкретно в данной ситуации код при использовании копии несколько упрощается. Очередную версию я привёл в ответе. Если этот вариант делает то что вам надо, то можете на досуге сравнить производительность с написанным вами. Если ваш работает ощутимо быстрее - добавьте тогда его ответом.

Comment: Код работает неверно. Для проверки перевел long.MaxValue в массив байт (`var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(long.MaxValue);`), затем сделал сдвиг влево вашей функцией, затем сделал для того же набора байт сдвиг таким образом (`var lbytesT = BitConverter.GetBytes(long.MaxValue << 1);`). Результаты отличаются. Попробуйте сами.

Comment: @iRumba а про little-endian порядок байтов в числе вы слышали? Если у вас он (а весьма похоже на то), и вы хотите сравнивать с `long`, то извольте делать `Array.reverse(bytes)` перед вызовом метода сдвига и `Array.reverse(lbytesT)` для сравнения результатов. Вопрос, напомню, про сдвиг массива байтов, а не про сдвиг байтов в `long`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я, возможно, чего то упустил, но я не пытался разбираться с порядком байтов в числе. Я больше скажу, я ничего об этом не подозревал. Я оперировал тем, что массив байт - это число. Маленькое (2 байта) или большое (20..Х байт). Поэтому я предположил, что сдвиг с небольшим набором байт (как в long, например) должен вернуть тот же результат, что и при сдвиге самого long. Да, проверил, с реверсом алгоритм работает, но проверить его  на скорость выполнения с учетом промежуточных преобразований проблематично.

Comment: в общем я Stopwatch Start() и Stop()поставил вокруг непосредственно операции сдвига внутри цикла. То есть операция преобразования не учитывается. Результат на 10000000 итераций - 22 СЕКУНДЫ. Всего должно было пройти 100 таких циклов, но я дождался одного и выключил. Это против моих 0,6-0.9 секунд. Выложу свой код позже, пока не дописал сдвиг вправо (времени не было). Там недолго, но времени нет :)

Comment: Немного обманул. Добавив свой сдвиг так же между start и stop я получил 1.2-1.4 сек. Видимо, накладные расходы на выполнение Stop(). Но в любом случае 1.4 секунды против 22 секунд.

Answer (score 2):

Можно было бы попробовать

```
return ((new System.Numerics.BigInteger(b)) << k).ToByteArray()
```

хотя потенциальные 3 копирования массива несколько настораживают.

Впрочем, можно заглянуть в его [исходники](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,1389) и как-то использовать соответствующий код:

```
public static BigInteger operator <<(BigInteger value, int shift) {

    if (shift == 0) return value;
    else if (shift == Int32.MinValue) return ((value >> Int32.MaxValue) >> 1);
    else if (shift < 0) return value >> -shift;

    int digitShift = shift / kcbitUint;
    int smallShift = shift - (digitShift * kcbitUint);

    uint[] xd; int xl; bool negx;
    negx = GetPartsForBitManipulation(ref value, out xd, out xl);

    int zl = xl + digitShift + 1;
    uint[] zd = new uint[zl];

    if (smallShift == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
            zd[i + digitShift] = xd[i];
        }
    } else {
        int carryShift = kcbitUint - smallShift;
        uint carry = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
            uint rot = xd[i];
            zd[i + digitShift] = rot << smallShift | carry;
            carry = rot >> carryShift;
        }
        zd[i + digitShift] = carry;
    }
    return new BigInteger(zd, negx);
}
```

Comment: А что такое `kcbitUint`? Что за функция `GetPartsForBitManipulation`?

Comment: `kcbitUint` - количество бит, в твоём случае - в байте, в их - в инте. `GetPartsForBitManipulation` - какая-то обработка сдвига отрицательных чисел - тебе тоже должна быть ненужна.

Comment: *ак мой мозг! Я написал свою функцию уже. Протестировал ее на 10^7 итераций. Отработало за 500 мс примерно. Сейчас запустил сдвиг BigInteger на 1 влево с тем же количеством итераций и... он до сих пор выполняется! Прошло уже более 4 минут! оО

Comment: А ну все правильно. BigInteger при сдвиге увеличивает количество байт. То есть это как если бы я делал свдиг для int, а в итоге мог бы получить long.

Comment: @iRumba, да BigInteger растёт) Но идею из их кода всё равно можно взять.

Comment: Да я вот смотрю, оказывается я делал по похожему принципу, вот только мой код более оптимизирован. У них `int digitShift = shift / kcbitUint;`, у меня `var byteShift = val >> 3;` и это работает раза в 3 быстрее. Ну есессно это верно если в байте 8 бит. :) Ну и в остальном тоже. Такое ощущение, что этот оператор для BigInt описывал студент

Comment: @iRumba, по идее, должен бы jit оптимизировать деление на константу? А даже если нет, это деление происходит только один раз.

Comment: Это не единственное деление там. К тому же подобные операции должны быть максимально быстрыми, потому как сами по себе они не представляют ценности. Один из возможных сценариев - хэширование. А значит они пойдут на цикл. Ну вы поняли )

Answer (score 1):

Сдвиг придётся реализовывать алгоритимчески: требуется на основе величины сдвига в цикле определить в какой байт попадут данные из текущего байта. Данные байта делятся на две части: смещённая и смещаемая часть.

Задание решить несложно, но это требует времени. Советую разбить задачу на несколько частей, например:
превратить любое отрицательное смещение в положительное;
сделать переход по всем байтам в цикле;
разбить байт на две части - та что выпала после смещения и вторая;
в локальные переменные записать значения новых индексов и смещения в их байтах для данных текущего байта;
записать в другой массив такой же длинны по смещённым индексам

Comment: Подумаю над этим. Как до студии доберусь. А то словами сложно представить код в голове и то, как он будет выполняться

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Rotates the bits in an array of bytes to the left.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">The byte array to rotate.</param>
public static void RotateLeft(byte[] bytes)
{
    bool carryFlag = ShiftLeft(bytes);

    if (carryFlag == true)
    {
        bytes[bytes.Length - 1] = (byte)(bytes[bytes.Length - 1] | 0x01);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Rotates the bits in an array of bytes to the right.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">The byte array to rotate.</param>
public static void RotateRight(byte[] bytes)
{
    bool carryFlag = ShiftRight(bytes);

    if (carryFlag == true)
    {
        bytes[0] = (byte)(bytes[0] | 0x80);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Shifts the bits in an array of bytes to the left.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">The byte array to shift.</param>
public static bool ShiftLeft(byte[] bytes)
{
    bool leftMostCarryFlag = false;

    // Iterate through the elements of the array from left to right.
    for (int index = 0; index < bytes.Length; index++)
    {
        // If the leftmost bit of the current byte is 1 then we have a carry.
        bool carryFlag = (bytes[index] & 0x80) > 0;

        if (index > 0)
        {
            if (carryFlag == true)
            {
                // Apply the carry to the rightmost bit of the current bytes neighbor to the left.
                bytes[index - 1] = (byte)(bytes[index - 1] | 0x01);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            leftMostCarryFlag = carryFlag;
        }

        bytes[index] = (byte)(bytes[index] << 1);
    }

    return leftMostCarryFlag;
}

/// <summary>
/// Shifts the bits in an array of bytes to the right.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">The byte array to shift.</param>
public static bool ShiftRight(byte[] bytes) 
{
    bool rightMostCarryFlag = false;
    int rightEnd = bytes.Length - 1;

    // Iterate through the elements of the array right to left.
    for (int index = rightEnd; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        // If the rightmost bit of the current byte is 1 then we have a carry.
        bool carryFlag = (bytes[index] & 0x01) > 0;

        if (index < rightEnd)
        {
            if (carryFlag == true)
            {
                // Apply the carry to the leftmost bit of the current bytes neighbor to the right.
                bytes[index + 1] = (byte)(bytes[index + 1] | 0x80);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rightMostCarryFlag = carryFlag;
        }

        bytes[index] = (byte)(bytes[index] >> 1);
    }

    return rightMostCarryFlag;
}
```

Comment: Вы авторство кода-то не забудьте указать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8450271/3432401

Comment: @Regent https://vk.com/images/stickers/150/64.png

Comment: Тут есть одно НО. Величина смещения не указывается